# "no python application found, check your startup logs for errors" when deploying Flask app with uWSGI

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to deploy my flask app so I am testing uWSGI serving.

blah/wsgi.py

```
from app import create_app

l_app = create_app()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app()
```

blah/app/__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from .config import Config as config_obj
from .views import app


def create_app():
    l_app = Flask(__name__)
    l_app.register_blueprint(app)
    return l_app
```

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:l_app
master = true
processes = 1
socket = /tmp/lapp.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

```
    location ~ ^/blah(.*)$ {
        include uwsgi_params;
         uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/lapp.sock;
         uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /app;
         uwsgi_param PATH_INFO /$1;
}
```

The command that I use is `uwsgi --ini myapp.ini`.

However I am getting an error that says 
`no python application found, check your startup logs for errors`
and in the browser it says "Internal Server Error".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way is to define:

```
module = wsgi
callable = l_app
```

You may also have to specify:

```
plugin = python
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tested it but still gives the same error.

Comment: Thank you I have managed to display a page but the layout is wiered. I am getting a error for static files. Do you have any idea how to fix this?